# How to read a string array which is part of Structure in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct

I am trying to figure out, how to scanf multiple strings into an array that is in a struct and print it out.

**I put two checks within the loops:**

check #1: Working Fine.

Check #2: Not Working.Somehow it puts all the strings into one array after the for loop instead of separating them like how it was within the for loop.

check #3: This will also have the same problem of check 2.

Should I declare another array order_t items[  ] to store the bins or what should I do? I am totally confused...

**I am trying to scanf as follows**

```
1000000 4
181 5c  915 4h  816 4g  716 10g
```

The meaning of the numbers:

(customer item_amount

bin_amount[0] bin[0], bin_amount[1] bin[1],.....etc.)

**Source Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ORDERS 100  /*maximum orders*/
#define MAX_ITEMS  10   /*maximum items in one order*/
#define BIN_CODE   2    /*maximum string for bin*/

/*struct 1: collect order number and item amount*/
typedef struct {
    int customer;
    int item_amount;
    char bin[MAX_ITEMS][BIN_CODE];
    int  bin_amount[MAX_ITEMS];
}order_t;

/*general function titles*/
void print_title(int stage);
int read_order(order_t orders[]);

/*main program*/
int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    order_t orders[MAX_ORDERS];

    /*obtain the data*/
    read_order(orders);
    /*check 3: if it prints*/
    printf("check3: %s\n", orders[0].bin[0]);

    return 0;
}

/*2: scanf file*/
int
read_order(order_t orders[]){
    int n=0, i;
    order_t new;

    while ((scanf("%7d %d\n", 
        &new.customer, 
        &new.item_amount)!=EOF) && (n<MAX_ORDERS)){
        for (i=0; i<new.item_amount; i++){
            scanf("%d %s  ",
            &new.bin_amount[i], new.bin[i]);
        /*check 1: if it print correctly within the for loop*/
        printf("check 1: %s\n", new.bin[i]);
        }
        scanf("\n");
        orders[n] = new;
        n += 1;
    }
    /*check 2: if it print as an array outside of for loop*/
    printf("check 2: %s\n", orders[0].bin[0]);
    return n;
}
```

**The results are:**

```
check 1: 5c
check 1: 4h
check 1: 4g
check 1: 10g
check 1: 1a
check 1: 1c
check 1: 2a
check 1: 2f
check 1: 1d
check 2: 5c4h4g10g
check3: 5c4h4g10g
```

Comment: `#define BIN_CODE   2` --> `#define BIN_CODE   (2+1)`

Comment: that works but y??

Comment: A space of `+1` is required for NUL characters.

Comment: Thanks, so basically I need to read \0!